# Is there to stop crashing of an app in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-navigation-bar

````
```2019-12-26 14:47:43.579 4853-4853/com.example.android.navigation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.navigation, PID: 4853
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.navigation/com.example.android.navigation.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.NavigationView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.navigation-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.navigation-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
    at com.example.android.navigation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)```
````

This is the logcat terminal my app which I am coding in android studio it  shows no error and succesfully installed but app stops afer installing in emulator, it doesn't even start it says "open app again" after reopen it says "app has stopped"
`Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037`
This error is also shown sometimes

Build.Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.android.navigation'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$version_kotlin"

    // Constraint Layout
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$version_constraint_layout"

    // Core
    implementation "androidx.core:core:$version_core"

    // Material Design
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$version_material"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0'

}
```

activity_xml file

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
                    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:defaultNavHost="true"
                    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
                    />
            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

android.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M6,18c0,0.55 0.45,1 1,1h1v3.5c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5L11,19h2v3.5c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5L16,19h1c0.55,0 1,-0.45 1,-1L18,8L6,8v10zM3.5,8C2.67,8 2,8.67 2,9.5v7c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5S5,17.33 5,16.5v-7C5,8.67 4.33,8 3.5,8zM20.5,8c-0.83,0 -1.5,0.67 -1.5,1.5v7c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5v-7c0,-0.83 -0.67,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5zM15.53,2.16l1.3,-1.3c0.2,-0.2 0.2,-0.51 0,-0.71 -0.2,-0.2 -0.51,-0.2 -0.71,0l-1.48,1.48C13.85,1.23 12.95,1 12,1c-0.96,0 -1.86,0.23 -2.66,0.63L7.85,0.15c-0.2,-0.2 -0.51,-0.2 -0.71,0 -0.2,0.2 -0.2,0.51 0,0.71l1.31,1.31C6.97,3.26 6,5.01 6,7h12c0,-1.99 -0.97,-3.75 -2.47,-4.84zM10,5L9,5L9,4h1v1zM15,5h-1L14,4h1v1z" />
</vector>
```

Please if any else file is required let me know
 navigation.xml

````
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/titleFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titleFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigation.TitleFragment"
        android:label="fragment_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_title">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_titleFragment_to_gameFragment"
            app:destination="@id/gameFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/gameFragment"
        android:name="com.example.android.navigation.GameFragment"
        android:label="fragment_game"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game" />
</navigation>```
````

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your issue and make your question clear on what exactly you want. I can see there is something wrong with your `NavigationView`, if you could post snippets of your code then we could help you.

Comment: *Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView*
 
 *Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView*
 
 *Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.NavigationView" on path: .....*
 
 Your error is so clear, read and try to fix it

Comment: -Hoàng Vũ Anh  I am still please give guide me with a detail solution